# How to select react function in getdocumentbyclass?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, browser, console

I dont know how to select function react in document.getElementsByClassName.

I have this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('card-list__card grid-layout-item grid-list-item')[0]

return 

"__reactInternalInstance$6xvjhfpf2k": Object { tag: 5, key: "545570876", elementType: "div", … }
```

This function __reactInternalInstance as random variable.

when I reload the page the function changes name
how I can select this to recover the key ?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('card-list__card grid-layout-item grid-list-item')[0].__reactInternalInstance*
```

is there an equivalent?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: You could iterate over the dom object's properties and see which one has the prefix `__reactInternalInstance`

Comment: iterate return undefined
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("card-list__card grid-layout-item grid-list-item")[0];
for (item in els){
 if(item.includes("__reactInternalInstance")){
  document.getElementsByClassName("card-list__card grid-layout-item grid-list-item")[0].item
 }
 
}

Comment: you used the wrong syntax, to use a variable as a key you use the `[]` notation, eg `els[item]`

Answer (score 0):

Use an id and use document.getElementById("yourIdGoesHere")

Comment: I don't have an id, the element is a class

Comment: Can you provide more code so we can help you further from where you are struggling?